# Can't access Bluemix object store from my Notebook

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read a couple of JSON files from my Bluemix object store into a Jupyter notebook using Python. I've followed the examples I've found, but I'm still getting a "No such file or directory" error.

Here is the code that should authenticate the object store and identify the files:

```
# Set up Spark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

if('config' not in globals()):
    config = SparkConf().setAppName('warehousing_sql').setMaster('local')
if('sc' not in globals()):
    sc= SparkContext(conf=config)

# Set the Hadoop configuration.
def set_hadoop_config(name, credentials):
    prefix = "fs.swift.service." + name
    hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.url", credentials['auth_url']+'/v3/auth/tokens')
    hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.endpoint.prefix", "endpoints")
    hconf.set(prefix + ".tenant", credentials['project_id'])
    hconf.set(prefix + ".username", credentials['user_id'])
    hconf.set(prefix + ".password", credentials['password'])
    hconf.setInt(prefix + ".http.port", 8080)
    hconf.set(prefix + ".region", credentials['region'])
    hconf.setBoolean(prefix + ".public", True)

# Data Sources (generated by Insert to code)
    credentials = {
  'auth_url':'https://identity.open.softlayer.com',
  'project':'***',
  'project_id':'****',
  'region':'dallas',
  'user_id':'****',
  'domain_id':'****',
  'domain_name':'****',
  'username':'****',
  'password':"""****""",
  'filename':'Warehousing-data.json',
  'container':'notebooks',
  'tenantId':'****'
}

set_hadoop_config('spark', credentials)

# The data files should now be accessible through URLs of the form
# swift://notebooks.spark/filename.json
```

Here is the calling code:

```
...
resource_path= "swift://notebooks.spark/"
Warehousing_data_json = "Warehousing-data.json"
Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json = "Warehousing-sales_data-nominal_scenario.json"
...
```

Here is the error:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'swift://notebooks.spark/Warehousing-data.json'

I'm sorry if this seems like a novice question (which I admit I am), but I think it's ridiculously complicated to set this up and really bad form to rely on an undocumented method SparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().

---

Added in response to Hobert's and Sven's comments:

Thanks Hobert. I don’t understand your comment about the definition for "swift://notebooks**.spark**/" Unless I misunderstand the logic of the sample I followed (which is essentially identical to what Sven shows in his response), this path results from the call to sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration(), but it’s hard to know what this call actually does, since the HadoopConfiguation class is not documented.

I also do not understand the alternatives to “use/add that definition for the Hadoop configuration” or “alternatively, … use swift client inside of Spark to access the JSON.” I suppose I would prefer the latter since I make no other use of Hadoop in my notebook. Please point me to a more detailed explanation of these alternatives.

Thanks Sven. You are correct that I did not show the actual reading of the JSON files. The reading actually occurs within a method that is part of the API for [DOcplexcloud](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/docloud/python-api/). Here is the relevant code in my notebook:

```
resource_path= "swift://notebooks.spark/"
Warehousing_data_json = "Warehousing-data.json"
Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json = "Warehousing-sales_data-nominal_scenario.json"

resp = client.execute(input= [{'name': "warehousing.mod",
                               'file': StringIO(warehousing_data_dotmod + warehousing_inputs + warehousing_dotmod + warehousing_outputs)},
                              {'name': Warehousing_data_json,
                               'filename': resource_path + Warehousing_data_json},
                              {'name': Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json,
                               'filename': resource_path + Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json}],
                      output= "results.json",
                      load_solution= True,
                      log= "solver.log",
                      gzip= True,
                      waittime= 300,
                      delete_on_completion= True)
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-67cf709788b3> in <module>()
     29                       gzip= True,
     30                       waittime= 300,
---> 31                       delete_on_completion= True)
     32 
     33 result = WarehousingResult(json.loads(resp.solution.decode("utf-8")))

/gpfs/fs01/user/sbf1-4c17d3407da8d0-a7ea98a5cc6d/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docloud/job.pyc in execute(self, input, output, load_solution, log, delete_on_completion, timeout, waittime, gzip, parameters)
    496         # submit job
    497         jobid = self.submit(input=input, timeout=timeout, gzip=gzip,
--> 498                             parameters=parameters)
    499         response = None
    500         completed = False

/gpfs/fs01/user/sbf1-4c17d3407da8d0-a7ea98a5cc6d/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docloud/job.pyc in submit(self, input, timeout, gzip, parameters)
    436                                 gzip=gzip,
    437                                 timeout=timeout,
--> 438                                 parameters=parameters)
    439         # run model
    440         self.execute_job(jobid, timeout=timeout)

/gpfs/fs01/user/sbf1-4c17d3407da8d0-a7ea98a5cc6d/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docloud/job.pyc in create_job(self, **kwargs)
    620                 self.upload_job_attachment(job_id, 
    621                                            attid=inp.name,
--> 622                                            data=inp.get_data(),
    623                                            gzip=gzip)
    624         return job_id

/gpfs/fs01/user/sbf1-4c17d3407da8d0-a7ea98a5cc6d/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docloud/job.pyc in get_data(self)
    110         data = self.data
    111         if self.filename is not None:
--> 112             with open(self.filename, "rb") as f:
    113                 data = f.read()
    114         if self.file is not None:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'swift://notebooks.spark/Warehousing-data.json'
```

This notebook works just fine when I run it locally and resource_path is a path on my own machine.

Sven, your code seems pretty much identical to what I have, and it follows closely the sample I copied, so I do not understand why yours works and mine doesn’t.

I have verified that the files are present on my Instance_objectstore. Therefore it seems that swift://notebooks.spark/ does not point to this objectstore. How that would happen has been a mystery to me from the start. Again, the HadoopConfiguation class is not documented, so it is not possible to know how it makes the association between the URL and the objectstore.

Comment: Hey J. Bloom, excellent question! When looking at your resource_path, I'm not seeing the definition for `"swift://notebooks**.spark**/" in the code above. I can attempt to rework the code to use/add that definition for the Hadoop configuration. Alternatively, you can also use swift client inside of Spark to access the JSON. Which approach would you like to pursue?

Comment: In your calling code, there are some lines of code missing for the actual reading of a json file e.g. `sc.textFile()` or `sqlContext.read.json()`. Can you please add those lines and maybe the first part of the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'swift://notebooks.spark/Warehousing-data.json'` means that at that path there is no such file. I think the setup of the Hadoop configuration was successful otherwise you would get a different error message complaining about missing credentials settings.

I have tested in a Python notebook on Bluemix the following code and it worked for me. I took the sample code from the latest sample notebooks showing how to load data from Bluemix Object Storage V3.

Method for setting the Hadoop configuration:

```
def set_hadoop_config(credentials):
    """This function sets the Hadoop configuration with given credentials, 
    so it is possible to access data using SparkContext"""

    prefix = "fs.swift.service." + credentials['name']
    hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.url", credentials['auth_url']+'/v3/auth/tokens')
    hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.endpoint.prefix", "endpoints")
    hconf.set(prefix + ".tenant", credentials['project_id'])
    hconf.set(prefix + ".username", credentials['user_id'])
    hconf.set(prefix + ".password", credentials['password'])
    hconf.setInt(prefix + ".http.port", 8080)
    hconf.set(prefix + ".region", credentials['region'])
    hconf.setBoolean(prefix + ".public", True)
```

Insert credentials for associated Bluemix Object Storave V3:

```
credentials_1 = {
  'auth_url':'https://identity.open.softlayer.com',
  'project':'***',
  'project_id':'***',
  'region':'dallas',
  'user_id':'***',
  'domain_id':'***',
  'domain_name':'***',
  'username':'***',
  'password':"""***""",
  'filename':'people.json',
  'container':'notebooks',
  'tenantId':'***'
}
```

Set Hadopp configuration with given credentials:

```
credentials_1['name'] = 'spark'
set_hadoop_config(credentials_1)
```

Read JSON file usind `sc.textFile()` into an `RDD` and print out first 5 rows:

```
data_rdd = sc.textFile("swift://" + credentials_1['container'] + "." + credentials_1['name'] + "/" + credentials_1['filename'])
data_rdd.take(3)
```

Output:

```
[u'{"name":"Michael"}',
 u'{"name":"Andy", "age":30}',
 u'{"name":"Justin", "age":19}']
```

Read JSON file using `sqlContext.read.json()` into a `DataFrame`and output first 5 rows:

```
data_df = sqlContext.read.json("swift://" + credentials_1['container'] + "." + credentials_1['name'] + "/" + credentials_1['filename'])
data_df.take(3)
```

Output:

```
[Row(age=None, name=u'Michael'),
 Row(age=30, name=u'Andy'),
 Row(age=19, name=u'Justin')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution at https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/using-ibm-object-storage-in-bluemix-with-python/ with sample code at https://github.com/saviosaldanha/IBM_Object_Store_Python_Example/blob/master/storage_recipe_example.py

Here is the revised code:

```
import swiftclient
from keystoneclient import client

# Object Store credentials (generated by Insert to code)
credentials = {
  'auth_url':'https://identity.open.softlayer.com',
  'project':'***',
  'project_id':'***',
  'region':'dallas',
  'user_id':'***',
  'domain_id':'***',
  'domain_name':'***',
  'username':'***',
  'password':"""***""",
  'filename':'Warehousing-data.json',
  'container':'notebooks',
  'tenantId':'***'
}

# Establish Connection to Bluemix Object Store
connection = swiftclient.Connection(
    key=credentials[password],
    authurl=credentials[auth_url],
    auth_version='3',
    os_options={"project_id": credentials[projectId],
                "user_id": credentials[userId],
                "region_name": credentials[region]})

# The data files should now be accessible through calls of the form
# connection.get_object(credentials[container], fileName)[1]
```

Then the files are accessed as:

```
Warehousing_data_json = "Warehousing-data.json"
Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json = "Warehousing-sales_data-nominal_scenario.json"

resp = client.execute(input= [{'name': "warehousing.mod",
                               'file': StringIO(warehousing_data_dotmod + warehousing_inputs + warehousing_dotmod + warehousing_outputs)},
                              {'name': Warehousing_data_json,
                               'filename': connection.get_object(credentials[container], Warehousing_data_json)[1]},
                              {'name': Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json,
                               'filename': connection.get_object(credentials[container], Warehousing_sales_data_nominal_scenario_json)[1]}],
                              output= "results.json",
                              load_solution= True,
                              log= "solver.log",
                              gzip= True,
                              waittime= 300,
                              delete_on_completion= True)
```

The problem is how to load the libraries swiftclient and keystoneclient in Bluemix? Pip doesn't seem to work in the notebook. Anyone know how to handle this?