# Loading (Geo)JSON from IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: json, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-storage

How can I load a JSON file from my cloud-object-storage into my Jupyter notebook as a string file and not as a streaming body.

The following code gives me a streaming object:

```
jsonfile = client_cred.get_object(Bucket='bucket_name',Key='file.json')['Body']
if not hasattr(jsonfile, "__iter__"): jsonfile.__iter__ = types.MethodType( __iter__, jsonfile)
```

This returns nothing ('NoneType'):

```
nyc_geo = client_cred.download_file(Bucket='bucket_name',Key='file.json',Filename='file.json')
```

This is probably really basic. Can somebody help?

Comment: Show complete examples with error messages and not code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

@Basti, 
I've worked with this recently. I had a similar issue. I was able to find my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061860/cant-access-bluemix-object-store-from-my-notebook) -- also, take a look at the reference to this IBM [sample code](https://github.com/saviosaldanha/IBM_Object_Store_Python_Example/blob/master/storage_recipe_example.py).